# How do I apply a CDataColumn filter to my CGridView so it displays only rows with a null-value?

Tags: yii

I have a model with a boolean value, generated from a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE receivable (
    ...
    is_paid INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    ...
)
```

You should only take notice of the possible NULL value.

I have a gii-generated Receivable.php-model and a simple CGridView, like this:

```
$dataProvider = $model->search();
$dataProvider->pagination = ['pageSize'=>20]; 
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        [
            'name'=>'is_paid',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>'($data->is_paid==1)?"PAID":"";',
            'filter'=>['1'=>'PAID', '0'=>'0']
        ],
        'someothercolumn',
        ['class'=>'CButtonColumn']
    ),
);
```

It should make sense so far? It does work fine I must say, with just one tiny problem - I want to allow filtering on null values as well!

```
'filter'=>['1'=>'PAID', '0'=>'0', null=>'null']  // This shows all records. 
'filter'=>['1'=>'PAID', '0'=>'0', ''=>'null']    // This also shows all records.
'filter'=>['1'=>'PAID', '<>1'=>'null or zero']   // This shows 0-records only.
```

Well, now I'm at a loss. Is there any way I can use the CDataColumn.filter to allow the user to filter on null values? (Only display rows where 'is_paid'==null)

Edit: **Values can be 1,0 or NULL, but the filter can only be applied for 1 or 0 (or show everything). How can I let the user display rows with null-values only?**

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is one way you can do it

```
1.'filter' => array('0' => Yii::t('app', 'No'), '1' => Yii::t('app', 'Yes')),
```

or something like this

```
2.is_paid:boolean
```

or something like this

```
3.'filter' => CHtml::listData(UserRegistry::model()->findAll(), 'id_user_registry', 'firstname' ),
```

In the above example i have the values in a db table

or something like this

```
4.'filter' => Lookup::items('option'),
```

and for the above example in the model you would have something like this

```
4. public static function items($type, $code)
        {
            if(!isset(self::$_items[$type]))
                self::loadItems($type);
            return isset(self::$_items[$type][$code]) ? self::$_items[$type][$code] : false;           
        }

        private static function loadItems($type)
        {
            self::$_items[$type]=array();
            $models=self::model()->findAll(array(
                'condition'=>'type=:type',
                'params'=>array(':type'=>$type),
                //'order'=>'position',
            ));
            foreach($models as $model)
                self::$_items[$type][$model->code]=$model->name;
        }
```

Comment: > array('0' => Yii::t('app', 'No'), '1' => Yii::t('app', 'Yes')).  This works for ones and zeros. But how do I target null values? Values can be 1,0 or NULL, but I can only filter for 1,0 or ALL. I want the user to be able to use the filter to display only rows that has a NULL-value. I'll look into your other solutions now, but I think you missed my question. Sorry for being unclear! I edited the title now.

Comment: your question is correct i didn't pay attention and i missed the part with the null , try giving a look at this-> Handle NULL value in CgridView = http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/17235-solved-handle-null-value-in-cgridview/ , if you are still having problems let me know

Comment: why exactly do you want to use null as a value? make them default to 0 when creating entry, or make record int and use 0,1,2 as status if you need more then 2 statuses for your entry.  its very tricky to use null as a filtering option

Comment: Sorry for the long wait. I'll accept this as the answer (as it is the only answer). As Tavi says I believe the correct solution is to avoid null values from the get go. Thank you.